# With flexbox, force columns to wrap text instead of cause container to overflow from its parent

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flex container with three columns. The center column fills the space between the left and right. I need to force the left and right columns to wrap the their text when the container becomes narrower, instead of extruding the container to the right side of the page. How can I do this?

```css
#main-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  height: 30px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

#center-content {
  border: 1px solid green;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

#left-content, #right-content {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.box {
  height: 20px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
  <div id="main-container">
    <div id="left-content" class="box">
      asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf
    </div>
    <div id="center-content" class="box">
      asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf
    </div>
    <div id="right-content" class="box">
      asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `flex: 1` on `#center-content` element.

```css
#main-container {
  display: flex;
}
#center-content {
  border: 1px solid green;
  flex: 1;
}
#left-content,
#right-content {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-container">
  <div id="left-content" class="box">
    asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf
  </div>
  <div id="center-content" class="box">
    asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf
  </div>
  <div id="right-content" class="box">
    asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the `flex` property to `0 auto` instead. Take a look at this handy guide on [CSS-Tricks about Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#article-header-id-13). Specifically, the part about the shorthand `flex` property you used:

> This is the shorthand for flex-grow, flex-shrink and flex-basis combined. The second and third parameters (flex-shrink and flex-basis) are optional. Default is 0 1 auto.

Your issue was because you were telling the flexible items to 'grow' too much compared to the other siblings elements.

```css
#main-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  height: 30px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

#center-content {
  border: 1px solid green;
  flex: 0 auto;
}

#left-content, #right-content {
  flex: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.box {
  height: 20px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
  <div id="main-container">
    <div id="left-content" class="box">
      asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf
    </div>
    <div id="center-content" class="box">
      asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf
    </div>
    <div id="right-content" class="box">
      asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf
    </div>
  </div>
```